# How does Gradle resolve the javaee-api dependency to build an EAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, dependency-injection, ejb, ear

I see that there's an `EAR` [plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html) for Gradle.  How is it used to build an `EAR`?  Yes, there's an `ear` task.  To build an `EAR` with an `EJB` module there's a [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) on java-ee.

How is that dependency resolved?

https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/why-gradle-doesnt-provide-provided/

http://www.lordofthejars.com/2015/10/gradle-and-java-ee.html

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_only_one_dependency_you

I don't mind reading the fine manual -- just please specify a chapter at least rather than RTFM because the fine manual states:

> 51.4. Dependency management
>
> The Ear plugin adds two dependency configurations: deploy and earlib.
>   All dependencies in the deploy configuration are placed in the root of
>   the EAR archive, and are not transitive. All dependencies in the
>   earlib configuration are placed in the 'lib' directory in the EAR
>   archive and are transitive.

To my reading that doesn't explain in a concrete fashion how the `java-ee` dependency itself is resolved.

project (rough):

```
gradleEAR/
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── net
    │   │       └── bounceme
    │   │           └── doge
    │   │               ├── ejb
    │   │               │   ├── NewSessionBean.java
    │   │               │   └── NewSessionBeanRemote.java
    │   │               └── json
    │   │                   ├── JsonReaderClient.java
    │   │                   ├── JsonReader.java
    │   │                   ├── Main.java
    │   │                   ├── Marshaller.java
    │   │                   ├── MarshallJSON.java
    │   │                   ├── ObjectA.java
    │   │                   └── PropertiesReader.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── foo.json
    │       ├── json.json
    │       └── properties.properties
    └── test
        └── java

13 directories, 18 files
```

build file (broken dependencies):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'ear'
}

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': '3.4.0'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1'
/*
    provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
    provided 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
*/
}
```

Each attempt to resolve the dependency creates different errors.

What's the correct syntax to resolve the `javaee-api` dependency?  Please do refer me to the manual.

Comment: *Each attempt to resolve the dependency creates different errors*: then what are the attempts, and what are the errors? This dependency is resolved as any other dependency: it's an artifact, downloaded from a repo.

Comment: @JBNizet I asked follow up questions to clarify:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45808956/262852  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45808971/262852    https://stackoverflow.com/q/45808984/262852  for the errors.

Comment: @Thufir, `provided` is a configuration created on your own. You need to add `configurations { provided }` since gradle doesn't provide this configuration out-of-the-box. It's described in the article you linked: https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/why-gradle-doesnt-provide-provided/