# Gradle: Could not find method provided() (group)

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, gradle, ejb, ear

Why can't Gradle find the method `provided` when this is the syntax [specified](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) by Maven?

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ gradle clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR/build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleEAR'.
> Could not find method provided() for arguments [{group=javax, name=javaee-api, version=7.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.684 secs
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ 



plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'ear'
}

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': '3.4.0'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1'
    provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
}
```

In reference to:

[How does Gradle resolve the javaee-api dependency to build an EAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781064/how-does-gradle-resolve-the-javaee-api-dependency-to-build-an-ear)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use dependencies build with `provided` scope in maven. You might want to configure your `build.gradle` to the following:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
```

and then further make use of your dependencies as:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1'
    provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
}
```

---

Or you can follow [`compileOnly`](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes.html#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin) way of doing it as:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}
```

As also mentioned in the maven central repository [here](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar)

Comment: The `compileOnly` option worked; downloaded javaee-api-7.0.pom and associated, then built the `EAR` -- looks good.  Why does the maven page give different instructions?  Reading your link to the fine manual, thx.

Comment: @Thufir I would trust this rather https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar