# Gradle: Could not find method providedCompile()

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, build, ejb, ear

How are [this](http://www.lordofthejars.com/2015/10/gradle-and-java-ee.html) and [this](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_only_one_dependency_you) build file able to use `providedCompile`?

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ gradle clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR/build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleEAR'.
> Could not find method providedCompile() for arguments [javax:javaee-api:7.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.721 secs
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/gradleEAR$ 

plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'ear'
}

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': '3.4.0'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1'
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}
```

In reference to:

[How does Gradle resolve the javaee-api dependency to build an EAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781064/how-does-gradle-resolve-the-javaee-api-dependency-to-build-an-ear)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`providedCompile` is shipped with [`war`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) plugin. So you need to add:

```
plugins {
  // ...
  id 'war'
}
```

Comment: In my case I have war applied but its still providing me the same error.

Comment: where should that be added?

Comment: @PabloPazos, a the very beginning of your build script.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if you have a higher version of Gradle installed. For example you have:

```
gradle --version
```

giving

```
Gradle 5.0
```

but the project expects Gradle 2.10 or some other lower version of Gradle.

To solve this first try to use Gradle wrapper `./gradlew` (if included with project) instead of locally installed gradle. Or install a correct version of gradle and make it available using path variable.

Comment: by project, you mean the specific project which I would be working on?

Comment: Yes. Assuming the project is created by someone else.